# How to fix the ValueError when converting to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

An error in which timedata does not match my format.

This is the data example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'TransactionTime': ['Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019']})
```

This is my code:

```py
data['TransactionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TransactionTime'], format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    431             try:
--> 432                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    433                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-ed51a35d7ed3> in <module>
----> 1 data['TransactionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TransactionTime'], format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    726             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    727         else:
--> 728             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    729             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    730     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    433                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    434             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 435                 raise e
    436 
    437     if result is None:

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    398                 try:
    399                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
--> 400                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    401                     )
    402                     if "%Z" in format or "%z" in format:

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data 'Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' (match)
```

Comment: It would probably help you to look at what `data['TransactionTime']` is. According to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), it needs to be "int, float, str, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, Series DataFrame/dict-like" which it likely isn't if you're getting that error. Another possibility is that you're asking to format it like `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'`, and one or more of those fields does not exist in the given data. (see [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62370051/how-to-conver-sat-feb-02-125000-ist-2019-to-regular-datetime-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If your data has multiple time zones.

- Map the unique time zones to a corresponding UTC offset, and then localize.
- Once the `DateTime` column is created, the other columns can be dropped.

  - `df.drop(columns=['a', 'b', 'd', 'time', 'tz', 'Y', 'TTime'], inplace=True)`

```
import pandas as pd

# data and dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'TTime': ['Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019', 'Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 EST 2019']})

                        TTime
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 EST 2019

# split the string into components; assumes all strings are formatted similarly
df[['a', 'b', 'd', 'time', 'tz', 'Y']] = df.TTime.str.split(expand=True)

                        TTime    a    b   d      time   tz     Y
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00  IST  2019
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 EST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00  EST  2019

# create list of unique time zones
uni_tzs = df.tz.unique().tolist()
print(uni_tzs)
>>> ['IST', 'EST']

# UTC offset for each timezone
tzs = ['+05:30', '-05:00']

# combine into a dict
maps = dict(zip(uni_tzs, tzs))

# map the different time zones to their UTC offsets
df.tz = df.tz.map(maps)

# create the DateTime column and convert to a time zone of your choice
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df.Y + df.b + df.d + df.time + df.tz, format='%Y%b%d%H:%M:%S%z'), utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

                        TTime    a    b   d      time      tz     Y                  DateTime
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00  +05:30  2019 2019-02-02 12:50:00+05:30
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 EST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00  -05:00  2019 2019-02-02 23:20:00+05:30
```

#### Alternatively

- Map to a time zone name instead of an offset.

  - Use `%Z` instead of `%z`, in the `format` parameter.

```py
df_tzs = df.tz.unique().tolist()
tzs = ['Asia/Kolkata', 'US/Eastern']
maps = dict(zip(df_tzs, tzs))

df.tz = df.tz.map(maps)

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df.Y + df.b + df.d + df.time + df.tz, format='%Y%b%d%H:%M:%S%Z'), utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

                        TTime    a    b   d      time            tz     Y                  DateTime
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00  Asia/Kolkata  2019 2019-02-02 12:50:00+05:30
 Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 EST 2019  Sat  Feb  02  12:50:00    US/Eastern  2019 2019-02-02 23:20:00+05:30
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely the error originates from the problem that `%Z` cannot parse `IST` to the correct timezone. There are multiple timezones that can be abbreviated as 'IST', so it is ambiguous anyway.

To parse e.g. 'IST' to a specific timezone, you can define a mapping dict and supply that to `dateutil`'s parser.parse:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

tzmap = {'IST': dateutil.tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')}

data = pd.DataFrame({'TransactionTime': ['Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019']})

data['TransactionTime'] = data['TransactionTime'].apply(lambda t: dateutil.parser.parse(t, tzinfos=tzmap))

# data['TransactionTime']
# 0   2019-02-02 12:50:00+05:30
# Name: TransactionTime, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzfile('Asia/Calcutta')]
```