# How to conver 'Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019' to regular datetime in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I am trying to convert this column of my dataframe **'Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019'** to regular **datetime format ie(2019-05-02 12:00:00)** in python

How do i convert all the rows to this format?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364555/how-to-fix-the-valueerror-when-converting-to-datetime/62366146#62366146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need your datetime Python object to be timezone aware, you could just use `strptime` as follows:

```
dt = "Sat Feb 02 12:50:00 IST 2019"
out = datetime.strptime(dt, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S IST %Y")
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
2019-02-02 12:50:00
```